# String.format cant calculate frequency of numbers java

Tags: java, count, string.format

I have a program that counts number of letters in a textfile and I want the output to be

```
Letter         Amount            Freq
  A              46             9.3456%
  .              .                 .
  .              .                 .
  .              .                 .
  Z              2              0.0234%
```

And I have this code

```
        System.out.println("Letter           Amount           Freq"); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        System.out.println(String.format("%c                 %d\n     %5f", i + 'A', count[i], (count[i]/totChar)*100 + "%"));
```

I just get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
```

Can anybody tell what is wrong?

EDIT for new output:

```
    Letter         Amount            Freq
      A              46                  
                                    9.234%
      B              32                   
                                    4.437%
      .               .                   
      .
```

So here is the new output and as you see the freq is not on the same line as the others!

EDIT for new code:

```
        System.out.println("Letter:         Amount:         Frequence:"); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        System.out.println(String.format("   %c              %d\n                                %f%%", i + 'A', count[i], (count[i]/totChar)*100));
```

Comment: `(count[i]/totChar)*100 + "%"` will result in a string. Use format string `" ...    %5f%%"` and value `(count[i]/totChar)*100` instead. Also note that if `count` and `totChar` are integer types you'll not get the result you want, use `(count[i]/(double)totChar) * 100` in that case.

Comment: thanks @Thomas It doesnt come in the same row as the others now, is that possible to fix?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, it should be in the same row. Note that in the format string I suggested `...` means all the stuff you have at the front of yours - it's not a literal.

Comment: That does seem a little strange... Can you please post the new code?

Comment: @ewanc now its edited :) thanks for the help! new to StackOverflow aswell! Do you know what I mean?

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help. I see what you mean, I'm inclined to think there's some strange whitespace stuff going on there. Try this: `%.5f%%` (note the dot before the 5. This is just going to limit it to 5 decimal places. No idea if it will work!

Comment: Sorry, forget that last comment (unless you want that formatting!), I just spotted the problem. In the Amount column you are specifying a format of `%d\n`. This is a integer followed by a new line character. Remover the `\n` and you should be in business.

Comment: Yepp Now it worked :D thank you so much @ewanc my first encounter with String.format! Thanks :)

Comment: Excellent! No problem :)  String.format can be horrible if you don't use it very often, but you do get used to it if you do use it a lot. FYI this syntax is borrowed from C, so in future it may help to check the docs for C's printf function. Much of it should be transferable.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas has given you the correct answer in his comment, I'd just like to add a little explanation to that.

Your line :

```
System.out.println(String.format("%c                 %d\n     %5f", i + 'A', count[i], (count[i]/totChar)*100 + "%"));
```

Specifies a string with three arguments; a char, an int and a float. However when your arguments are evaluated one of them does not match the type specified. In this case you have correctly calculated your float value `(count[i]/totChar)*100` but you then append a %. This has the effect of converting the value into a String, in the same way you can add arithmetic when concatenating Strings, eg
`String x = "string with " + (0+1) + " ints";`

Instead the percentage sign should be added inside the String itself and not to any of the arguments (unless of course they also happen to be Strings).

@Thomas's suggestion of using `%5f%%` does exactly this. That's "%5f" for the format and "%%" for adding an escaped percentage sign.

Comment: Okej Thanks but now I get this output 


`Let          Amount        Frequency
A                 46          
                                  9,406953%
B                 9
                                  1,840491%
C                 13
                                  2,658487%`

Damn I cant get it to switch line, But I will try to describe it.

The letter and the amount is on the same row but the frequency belong to that letter is one row down

Comment: Yeah, the code snippets in comments don't work the same as in questions and answers, you lose a lot of formatting. Can you please add it into your question as an edit, I think that will be easier to follow.